# Chrome Dev Tools console says every page in my blog has link to http://maps.google.com

Tags: plugins, security, google-chrome

Viewing any page of my blog at https://www.rephunter.net/blog/ with the Chrome Dev Tools console open gives a Mixed Content error message.

[image: screen shot of Dev Tools console with error messages]

The problem is that I cannot find where that link is, and to my knowledge we do not use maps.google.com. I am thinking it might be buried somewhere in the theme.

How can I find out where this link is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely being hooked into `wp_head()`, probably with `wp_enqueue_scripts()`.

To find the culprit:

First, deactivate your theme, use a twentyx theme instead. Then refresh the front end and check the source code again.

If it's gone: its your theme. To find where its being called from in your theme, search your theme directory `/socrates4/` for some keywords, like `google.com` or `wp_head` or `enqueue`. (I'd guess it's in `functions.php` so if you're going to browse manually, that's a good place to start).

If it's not gone, it's not your theme: so try deactivating your plugins, one by one. Everytime you deactivate one, check the front end source code, and see if it's gone, you'll be able to find which plugin is causing it.

You can then either

- fix the plugin yourself (usually a bad idea if its hosted on wordpress.org as updates will overwrite your changes).
- leave a support ticket with the developer, and hope they do somthing about it
- keep it deactivated, delete it, and find a better plugin thats well written enough to not hard link `http`